# How to get more than one selecting result by using cursor?

Tags: java, cursor

I use cursor.movetonext to get the selecting result like this:

```
while(cursor.moveToNext()){
    int index2=cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_PASSWORD);
    String password=cursor.getString(index2);
    buffer.append(password);
}
return buffer.toString();
```

But each time, only one result could be returned. What if there are more than one result meet the selecting condition? How can I get all the result back in my main activity?

Comment: Use a collection of some sort

Comment: @user3580294 Could you tell me more details?

Comment: If you want to get multiple results back, store them in a collection (`ArrayList`, `HashMap`, etc.) while iterating and once you're done return that collection.

Comment: @user3580294 Can I use for loop to return them one by one? After one result is returned, will the cursor move to the next row?

Comment: Once you return from a method, your program exits the method, and so you cannot continue. You either return one result or all of them at once.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the `while(cursor.moveToNext())` loop does. If it iterates through all the result then your code should return all result as long as you have initialized buffer outside the loop.

Say if you have 3 password returned from query, "p1","p2" and "p3", then this method will concatenate all these together and return one string "p1p2p3".

The usual practice is to use java.sql.ResultSet and List to return multiple results. e.g.

```
List<String> listOfPasswords = new ArrayList<String>();
while(resultSet.next()){
    listOfPasswords.add(resultSet.getString(index));
}
return listOfPasswords;
```

Comment: but I use sqlite and cursor, how can I put the cursor select values in array? And after I get the return array, I have to decompose it to single value. How can I realize it then ?